# Insert YouTube iframe on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

I want to insert an iframe when user hovers on a div but it dosen't seem to be working. It works pretty well without the hover event but not `on hover` function.

html:

```
<div class="video_wrap"></div>
```

css:

```
.video_wrap {
    width: 320px;
    height: 240px;
    background: #b30054;
}
```

js:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script'),
    firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

$(".video_wrap").on({
    mouseenter: function () {

        $(this).attr('id', 'curr');

        var player;

        function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('curr', {
                height: '240',
                width: '320',
                videoId: 'wJnnT1SGEsc',
            });
        };

    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        //stuff to do on mouse leave
    }
});
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/508oknm7/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't declare the onyoutubeready function within the event handler. That event is dispatched once the script has been loaded, it makes no sense. Instead, you just construct the player within the hover.

```
$(".video_wrap").on({
    mouseenter: function () {

        $(this).prop('id', 'curr');

        player = new YT.Player('curr', {
            height: '240',
            width: '320',
            videoId: 'wJnnT1SGEsc',
        });


    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        //stuff to do on mouse leave
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/508oknm7/4/)